# Words in String-How to remove

Tags: java, string

I am trying to allow the user to remove a word from the string str.
For example if they type "Hello my name is john", The output should be "Hello is john".
How do i make this happen?

```
import java.util.*;
class WS7Q2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
        String str = in.nextLine();

        int j;

        String[] words = str.split(" "); 
        String firstTwo = words[0] + "  " + words[1]; // first two words
        String lastTwo = words[words.length - 2] + " " + words[words.length - 1];//last two   words 

        System.out.println(str);

    }
}
```

Comment: `str = str.replace("my name", "");`

Answer (score 2):

This is how you split the string

```
String myString = "Hello my name is John";

String str = myString.replace("my name", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

This will print "Hello is John"

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [String#replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
String hello = "Hello my name is john"

hello = hello.replace("my name", "");

System.out.println(hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is immutable in java, you cannot modify the string itself (not easily anyway, [can be done using reflection - but it is unadvised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6932772/572670)).

You can bind a new string to `str` with minimal changes to your code using something similar to:

```
str = firstTwo + " " + lastTwo;
```