# Is it ok to change a String value like this in Java?

Tags: java, string

I thought you can't change the value of a String once it has already been initialized to a value? Well apparently I can in my program below.

```
public class Pekka {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Person p = new Person("Pekka Mikkola", "040-123123");

        System.out.println(p.getName());
        System.out.println(p.getNumber());
        System.out.println(p);
        p.changeNumber("000-0001");
        System.out.println(p);



    }
}

class Person {

    private String name, number;

    Person(String name, String number){
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

    public void changeNumber(String newNumber){
        number = newNumber; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName() + "    number: " + getNumber();
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Pekka Mikkola
040-123123
Pekka Mikkola    number: 040-123123
Pekka Mikkola    number: 000-0001
```

So I can apparently change the value of the string number as many times as I want. How come? I can change the value of the variable "number" in the changeNumber method even though it has already been initialized? I thought Strings in Java once initialized can't be changed?

Comment: `toString()` will return a new string (String object on the heap) on every call.

Comment: You can change a variable to point to a new reference, a new real object.  You can't modify the contents of an immutable object.

Comment: You let the field `number` point to another object, another String. Every String object can be shared, as you cannot change its internal value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a String's value*, but you can assign a new, different String to a variable (unless the variable is `final`).

Your code is assigning a new String to the `number` variable:

```
public void changeNumber(String newNumber){
        number = newNumber; 
    }
```

The old String isn't being modified - it's being discarded.

`*` Actually, there *are* [ways to do this, using reflection](http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-modify-a-string-without-creating-a-new-one/), but it's [not usually a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932772/effect-of-changing-string-using-reflection).

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of a String, but assigning your variable `number` to a new String.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Java are immutable in the sense that once a string is allocated, its value cannot typically be changed. However, the allocation that the variable points to can change.

For example, consider the following:

`String test = "test";`

Memory gets allocated on the heap to store the string `"test"`. Now, if the following code is run:

`test = "test2";`

Then a new allocation is made to store the string `"test2"`, and the variable `test` now points to that allocation. The allocated value of a String is not changed, but the variable can always point to a different allocation. The only way to make a String variable's value not possible to change is to declare it as `final`.